# How can I disable it so that when I open the download-popup the background doesn't move with it? - Chrome

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome

Whenever the download-popup gets open my chat-box stays static but the background size is moving with the messages dynamically.

so if the curser is at the bottom it moves a little high as soon as the download popup is open

I tried to make the `position:fixed`, `height:100%` or the `z-index +/-10`

Unfortunately, I had to cut a few lines of code away so I could post it.

HTML:

```
<div id="chatContent{{i}}" class="row chat-content">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row mb-3 mt-2">
    <div class="col-12 input-group">
        <input id="userInput{{i}}" #userInput (keyup.enter)="sendMessage(userInput)"
               class="form-control form-control-lg"
               type="text" placeholder="Ask me something">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button mat-button
                    class="c-white bc-darkgreen bgc-darkgreen w-px-100 btn-left-no-round"
                    (click)="sendMessage(userInput);">
                <i *ngIf="sendBlock;then loader else send"></i>
                <ng-template #loader>
                    <fa class="fa fa-spin fa-2x" name="spinner"></fa>
                    <span class="sr-only">Sent!</span>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template #send>
                    Send
                </ng-template>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chat-block {
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.chat-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 75vh;
    height: calc(75vh - 100px);
    min-height: calc(75vh - 100px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    order: -10;
}

.chat-margin {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```